# How do you compare the length of multiple arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do you compare the length of multiple arrays in javascript.

Comment: Even if you intend to share your knowledge by answering your own questions (which is fine) The question should still follow the standard. Add required code with the problem, to allows others to replicate the issue, etc... As the question stands at the moment it's to broad and shows no research effort, etc...

Comment: Okay. Thanks man.

Comment: Why not do `args.every(x=>x.length=== args[0].length)`

Answer (score 3):

[Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) can also be used:

```js
var array1 = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 5]];
var array2 = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]];

function compareArraysLength(element, index, array) {
  return element.length === array[0].length;
}

console.log(array1.every(compareArraysLength));
console.log(array2.every(compareArraysLength));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function compareArraysLength(args) {
    // The argument should be an array that contain arrays
    var arrays = args;
    var noOfElements = arrays.length;
   var currentIndex = 0;

    while (currentIndex < noOfElements) {
        arrays.forEach(function(arg) {
            if (arrays[currentIndex].length !== arg.length) {
                throw new Error('All arrays must be of the same length');
            }
        });
        currentIndex += 1;
    }
}
```

I think this will be best. Thank @rajesh

```
function compareArraysLength(args) {
    return args.every(x=>x.length=== args[0].length)
}
```